# Dart: what is the fastest way to check if a particular symbol in a string is a digit?

Tags: dart

Of course I can do it via comparing it to 10 digits or even using regular expressions, but I'm looking for the fastest way possible.

Here is what I currently came up with, does it look reasonable?

```dart
int _zero = "0".codeUnits[0];
int _nine = "9".codeUnits[0];
bool isDigit(String s, int idx) => 
 s.codeUnits[idx] >= _zero && s.codeUnits[idx] <= _nine;
```

I'm a bit surprised that I haven't found this method in a standard library, hopefully I just missed it.

Comment: If you want fast, don't use `.codeUnits`. It creates an object wrapping the string, and then the `[idx]` just does `string.codeUnitAt(idx)`. Just do that directly. The compiler may optimize the overhead away, but why take chances.  You also don't want to call `codeUnitAt` twice for the same index - use a variable.   The constants _zero and _nine should be real constants, not lazily initialized mutable global variables, so `const _zero = 0x30; const _nine = 0x39;` so the compiler knows that they are constant. I'd write `{ final char = s.codeUnitAt(idx); return _nine >= char && zero <= char; }`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```dart
bool isDigit(String s, int idx) => (s.codeUnitAt(idx) ^ 0x30) <= 9;
```

for speed.

Comment: And we have a winner right here - on my micro-benchmark it is three times as fast as the previous fastest code. Elegant bit trick, too. Thank you!

Comment: I know it is a old question, but I just want to note that this method is (now) available in the quiver package.

https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.strings/isDigit.html

Answer (score 7):

I ran a quick micro-benchmark for the various alternatives and it seems it is pretty much a tie between [Günter's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25873172/1240320) and brute force checking. I prefer Günter's method for the elegance but if performance is absolutely critical, it seems brute force may win by a tiny margin. The benchmark runs each method once for an index that will return true and once for an index that will return false.

#### Brute force method:

```dart
bool isDigit(String s, int idx) {
  return s[idx] == "0"
      || s[idx] == "1"
      || s[idx] == "2"
      || s[idx] == "3"
      || s[idx] == "4"
      || s[idx] == "5"
      || s[idx] == "6"
      || s[idx] == "7"
      || s[idx] == "8"
      || s[idx] == "9";
}
```

0.045421617878512024 us.

#### Günter's method:

```dart
bool isDigit(String s, int idx) =>
  "0".compareTo(s[idx]) <= 0 && "9".compareTo(s[idx]) >= 0;
```

0.054188391470161947 us

#### Your code unit method:

```dart
int _zero = "0".codeUnits[0];
int _nine = "9".codeUnits[0];
bool isDigit(String s, int idx) => 
 s.codeUnits[idx] >= _zero && s.codeUnits[idx] <= _nine;
```

0.6344102870896872 us

This can be improved by 2x by storing the results of s.codeUnits[idx] (for some reason the VM cannot manage to optimize this away, unlike the other methods where repetitive s[idx] calls are optimized and not slower than storing an intermediate result):

```dart
 bool isDigit(String s, int idx) {
     int cuIdx = s.codeUnits[idx];
     cuIdx  >= _zero && cuIdx  <= _nine;
 }
```

0.29245961607948817 us

#### Regex method:

```dart
RegExp digitRegExp = new RegExp(r'\d');
bool isDigit(String s, int idx) => s[idx].contains(digitRegExp);
```

4.812064808888846 us

#### int.parse method (extremely slow):

```dart
bool isDigit(String s, int idx) {
  bool isDigit = true;
  try {
    int.parse(s[2]);
  } catch (e) {
    isDigit = false;
  }
  return isDigit;
}
```

102.48526774276198 us

Answer (score 3):

Looks fine to me, as long as you don't use unicode characters.

A similar attempt, but I wouldn't expect this to be faster:

```dart
bool isDigit(String s, int idx) =>
  "0".compareTo(s[idx]) <= 0 && "9".compareTo(s[idx]) >= 0;
```

Would be interesting if the compiler optimizes this duplicate `s[idx]`/`s.codeUnits[idx]` away - but I would expect so.

Comment: You've got the code a bit mixed up - this won't return the correct results. Both comparison should be <= 0.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, fixed

Comment: My micro-benchmark showed that the compiler did not optimize the duplicate s.codeUnits[idx] - although based on monitoring the activity happening on DartVM I expect this to change in the future.

Comment: How did you deduce that? I thought the brute force attempt shows that this is optimized away, otherwise it wouldn't be so fast I think.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer You are wrong, your code is about 5 times faster than my initial attempt and also much more elegant (I don't like having constants that are visible on the package level) - thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Well, my initial version works twice as fast if I store the result of s.codeUnits[idx] and do not call it twice, so I assumed the VM did not do it by itself.

Comment: I thought about asking @Pixelelephant to add such a version to his benchmarks but after I saw the brute force result I thought this is redundant.

Comment: I tested with removing dupes and it seems to make no difference except for @AndrewSkalkin codeunit method, where as he says it is about twice as fast. I'm not sure exactly why that is.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the info. `s.codeUnits` seems to add something that prevents the compiler from optimizing.